# How can I add this Tripadvisor widget to my React site?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to add a Tripadvisor rating widget to my React website (see code below). At the moment, only the Tripadvisor log is loading, and no rating information. I think the script in the widget is not running, and I'm not sure how to get it to run.

I loaded the script using Helmet, and can see it in the head of my document in the browser. In the same component, I try to render the widget.

```
//Here is the code of the widget:


<div id="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow350" class="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow">
       <ul id="80bNGet6b" class="TA_links mE4BAE">
          <li id="u9nO7YH4pF" class="aWtKBjB9S">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/">
              <img
                src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png"
                alt="TripAdvisor"
              />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>

<script
   async
   src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs
wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&amp;uniq=350&amp;locationId=17821239&amp;lang=en_US&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"
   data-loadtrk
   onload="this.loadtrk=true">
</script>


//Here is the code of my attempt:


const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Helmet>
        <script
          async
          src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&amp;uniq=350&amp;locationId=17821239&amp;lang=en_US&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"
          data-loadtrk
          onload="this.loadtrk=true"
        ></script>
      </Helmet>
      <div id="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow350" class="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow">
        <ul id="80bNGet6b" class="TA_links mE4BAE">
          <li id="u9nO7YH4pF" class="aWtKBjB9S">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/">
              <img
                src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_log o_transp_340x80-18034-2.png"
                alt="TripAdvisor"
              />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</Layout>


I expect the full tripadvisor widget to load, but instead it just loads the Tripadvisor logo image (which does not require the script to be run).

The widget looks fine when I test it in a plain html document, but I can't get it to work in React. Any help much appreciated!
```

Comment: Hi, what errors are you getting in console?

Comment: please share the full code and console error

Comment: Hi - no errors in the console I could find, but it's working now after doing a proper build (was running in gatsby dev mode before).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question.  Receiving errors in the console (by right clicking and choosing *inspect* in Chrome) would be helpful to determine the root of the problem.

I think what's happening here is a conflict associated with the security of the site.

In the line that identifies the jscashe.com URL, use this URL instead: https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-cdsratingsonlynarrow?amp;locationId=17821239&border=true&uniq=350&lang=en_US&display_version=2

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked the console and couldn't find any related errors. However I did a proper build and deploy (I was running it in develop mode before) and it's working fine now. Must be something to do with building the site properly? Would be interested to know why that effects it if you know.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that by doing a `gatsby build && gatsby serve` the widget works fine. I was previously running `gatsby develop` and it wasn't working then. If anyone knows why that could be I would be interested to know!